# Developing with different versions of dependencies

Tags: git, composer-php

We are developing a PHP application and multiple module dependencies for it. In development we would like to use dev branches and in production tagged versions.
Problem is that some of those modules depend on each other.

What is the best practice to handle the workflow here?

Because if in the main app we require dev versions everyone has to remember to change it before merging to master.
One solution would be to use a separate composer.json file to developing but I think that wouldn't work with dependencies of dependencies.

To illustrate:

Main app composer.json in develop:

```
"module_1": "dev-develop",
"module_2": "dev-develop",
```

In "module_1" composer.json:

```
"module_3": "dev-develop"
```

---

In production main composer.json:

```
"module_1": "^1.0.0",
"module_2": "^1.0.0",
```

In "module_1" composer.json:

```
"module_3": "^1.0.0"
```

Comment: One could remove `composer.json` from version control and instead check in the two files `composer.json-template-develop` and `composer.json-template-main`.

Comment: That's actually not a bad solution. Dunno why I haven't thought of it.
If no one comes up with a better solution we'll do this.

Comment: Could you explain why you developt against dev branches? That sounds like needlessly runnign the risk of having things break once you switch to the release versions. So what's the point?

Comment: Because the module functionality can only be tested in the main app. So we have to run 'composer update'. And it can't be merged to master and tagged before testing.

Comment: Ah, I see. Then what about the opposite approach: Keep the dev versions, and only switch to production versions right before release? That's what we did on another project.

Comment: That's what we do right now. But it's a hassle especially when we have to update not just dependencies in the main app but also all dependencies of modules that require our other modules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One could remove `composer.json` from version control and instead check in the two files `composer.json-template-develop` and `composer.json-template-main`.

Note that this generalizes to all configuration files. It makes the difference between version control and deployment more explicit. It is also recommended by Subversion, quoting the [FAQ:](https://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#ignore-commit)

> **I have a file in my project that every developer must change, but I don't want those local mods to ever be committed. How can I make 'svn commit' ignore the file?**
>
> The answer is: don't put that file under version control. Instead, put a template of the file under version control, something like "file.tmpl".
>
> Then, after the initial 'svn checkout', have your users (or your build system) do a normal OS copy of the template to the proper filename, and have users customize the copy. The file is unversioned, so it will never be committed. And if you wish, you can add the file to its parent directory's svn:ignore property, so it doesn't show up as '?' in the 'svn status' command.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to challenge the premise and say:

**Don't do this.**

Generally you should try to keep as close to the production release as possible during development. That means testing in an environment that is close to production, using data that is close to production data, and using the versions of dependencies that will be used in production. Any deviation from that increases the risk of missing bugs that are hidden by the deviation.

Sometimes it is inevitable to deviate from production (new version of dependency required for new feature, production data cannot be used due to privacy concerns, etc.), but that is the goal you should strive for.

---

That said, if you absolutely must have different dependencies during development:

> Because if in the main app we require dev versions everyone has to
>   remember to change it before merging to master.

This seems to indicate you develop features on branches, then merge to master.
If that is the case, then the cleanest solution would be to **change to production versions before the merge**.

The whole point of having feature branches is to test the code before merging it. Properly testing it requires using the dependencies that will be used on master. So, your merge workflow should be:

- switch versions of dependencies to the "production versions" (you may want to hack up a script to do this if it's a lot of work)
- re-test everything to make sure the switch did not break everything
- merge (no merge conflicts in `composer.json` because it's the same on master)

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment above - the idea is to test before merging.
But functionality of modules (not unit or feature tests) need to be tested in main app and they are required via composer.
So the problem is that I don't know how to best manage this without changing required versions all the time and that's a mess.